# Silverlight TelerikGrid 'EndsWith' Filter is Not Working for values having Leading Spaces (Trailing Spaces)

Tags: silverlight, telerik-grid, spaces, trailing

I'm having problem binding the data to the grid when I filter using the operator `EndsWith`.

```
fieldfilter.Filter1.Operator.ToString == "IsEqualTo"
fieldFilter.Filter1.Value = fieldFilter1.Value.ToString().PadRight(120, ' ');
```

In the database the values of the column have the Leading Spaces, and I had problem making it work for `IsEqualTo` also but I fixed it by padding leading spaces to the right of the input string. (as shown below)

But, I'm not sure how I should do it for the `EndsWith` Filter Operator.

I'm able to get the rows from the database by using where condition like '%ABC'.

But the rows are not binding to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the  callback from DB with the collection(collection).

```
queueColl = new HierarchyItemCollection();// the original collection- before
            List<HierarchyItem> items = new List<HierarchyItem>(collection.OrderBy(item => item.Text));

            items.ForEach(item =>
            {
                item.Tag = (stcQueue)item.Tag;
                item.ObjectData = null;
                queueColl.Add(item);
            });

            radTreeOH.DataContext = queueColl; // I am having a tree.
```